# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main" Process completed?

Tags: java

```
plz what wrong in my code !!
```

its my assignment ..so plz your help
its say process completed but when i try to run it its say main error exception in thread????
......................
 plz what wrong in my code !! 
its my assignment ..so plz your help
its say process completed but when i try to run it its say main error exception in thread????
 plz what wrong in my code !! 
its my assignment ..so plz your help
its say process completed but when i try to run it its say main error exception in thread????

```
import java.util.*;
class tests{
    Scanner te=new Scanner(System.in);
 String et;
 String tt;
 String dst;
 String rt;

 int test;
 String result1="Pass";
 String result2="fail";
 void chosetest(){
    System.out.println("Chose test :");
    test=te.nextInt();
    switch(test){
        case 1:System.out.println("Eys test"+et);break;
        case 2:System.out.println("Traffic sing  test"+tt);break;
        case 3:System.out.println("Drum and slope test"+dst);break;
        case 4:System.out.println("Road test"+rt);break;
        default:System.out.println("No test");
    }
 }

void resultoftest(){
    System.out.println("Enter test result:" );

    if ((result1=="Pass")&&(test==1)){
        System.out.println("Go to traffic sing test ");
    }
    else if ((result2=="fail")&&(test==1)){
        System.out.println("Try agin");
 }

 else if ((result1=="Pass")&&(test==2)){
        System.out.println("Go to drum and slope test ");
    }
    else if ((result2=="fail")&&(test==2)){
        System.out.println("Try agin");
 }

    else if ((result1=="Pass")&&(test==3)){
        System.out.println("Go to road test ");
    }
    else if ((result2=="fail")&&(test==3)){
        System.out.println("Try agin");
 }

    else if ((result1=="Pass")&&(test==4)){
        System.out.println("Get your driving licene ");
    }
    else if ((result2=="fail")&&(test==4)){
        System.out.println("Try agin");
 }
 System.out.println("The result "+test+ "=" +result1);
 System.out.println("The result "+test+ "=" +result2);

 }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to have a `main` function, so your program doesn't have an entry point. What code do you expect to run when your program starts?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `main()` method to your class. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here , all you need to create a controller to instantiate the process.
For Example, put this above into a class "ClassA" and then create main file like below
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("herehere");

ClassA classa = new ClassA();
   classa.resultoftest();

}

}

hope that helpful